# Why app is not compatible with Samsung S5 (Screen size 5.1) even though Google Play listing it is compatible

Tags: android

Hello I want to know that why Google Play is showing "Your device isn't compatible with this version" on Samsung S5

When I saw developer console there it displays that app is compatible with Samsung S5 and Nexus 5,6 etc all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <permission
            android:name="com.example.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="false"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="false" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.example.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.WRITE_GMAIL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="9"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
            android:required="false" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
            android:largeHeap="true">

            // here activies, receivers, services

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance it's the screen size?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Screen size 5.1

Comment: @Williams indeed, and 5.1" is pretty... large. It's probably the `android:largeScreens="false"` rule that's blocking it.

Comment: @Barend Yes. But Google Play developer console showing it is compatible on Samsung S5.

Comment: and If I remove this I want my application work on phones not on tablets. How I can do that

Comment: Never mind. According to http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/record/lod.htm, the Galaxy S5 (SM-G900) is a normal, not a large.

Comment: @Barend then issue is something else right ?

Comment: Only way to be sure is to give it a try.

Comment: When you look at the android docs, devices smaller than 4" and above 7" are considered large, so there's some overlap. Perhaps they (os/samsung) don't come to the same conclusion of the size. [..."7" tablet is technically in the same group as a 5" handset (the large group)."](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: @Barend What I should try, Can you please hint

Comment: Do you have the app running on a dev machine that you can try it out; if so, does it run in that environment?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, it runs on Samsung S5 Genymotion device

Comment: @Williams put `android:largeScreens="true"` in the manifest and see if it installs on the S5.

Comment: @Barend For this I have to release the build on Google Play, not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
```

to

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"  />
```

This is the only feature that has required to true. 
And I dont see this feature on the Galaxy S5 ATT

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple versions of the `Samsung Galaxy S5`. You can check the already accepted phones and you will find multiple versions of the same phone that are already accepted. Maybe this version is lacking something that you have a permission for.

Comment: It is this one http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-G900AZKAATT on which it is not compatible

Comment: seems to me that it don't lack any of what you requested in the manifest!

Comment: Ok but anything which I requested is not there ? How I can I know this ? Can you please help